# Swift: Prevent gameplayer address tracking

Tags: swift, memory-address

I'm developing a simple game in swift, but using GamePlayer (on Cydia, a `cheat-engine`like), I am able to locate, track and modify my score.

I was wondering how can I prevent this kind of cheats... I tried to create a new instance of the element whenever it changes, example:

```
score = Int(score + 1)
```

I also tried to reset the var to nil and re-assign it:

```
let tmp = score + 1
score = nil
score = tmp
```

But it is not working... 
My first question is: Is it possible to change a variable's address in swift ? And will it prevent address tracking?

My second question is: Another thing that can work, encoding my score, but is it worth the work ?

Comment: Usually "security by obscurity" doesn't work at all. But here it can help. A classic trick is to generate a unique key for each game. Do not change your score variable directly, use a dedicated method to do it, where you *also* udpate a private variable where you store the score multiplied by this secret key (or bitshifted or stringified and mangled or whatever). When you read the score variable, always compare it to its secret counterpart by doing the inverse operation. If the score has been tempered with at runtime, you'll know it because the secret variable would not be in sync anymore.

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean and this can be implemented pretty quickly ! But just for my general knowledge, do you know if it is possible to change a variable's address in swift ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `score` variable in a `struct` and use copy-on-write. Then, when you change a value, you get a fresh copy of the `score`. The possibilities and how copy-on-write works, is described here with examples: [copy-on-write](https://www.raywenderlich.com/112029/reference-value-types-in-swift-part-2)

Compared to the solution, were you actually encrypt the number it has advantages and disadvantages. Just some of them from the top of my head (I'm curious what your points are)

- encryption needs more cpu power and therefore more battery. Whereas the copy-on-write is implemented deep on iOS level, where we can assume, that it is very well optimised.
- The copy-on-write solution is less secure, as one might find the right address just at the beginning and can track it (now, that I think about it, not really...)
- The copy-on-write adds more complexity to your source code as you need to trigger it on every change.